# Convert PDF to thumbnail - Could not connect to display

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a program that convert PDF to create thumbnails. It use the this convert command :

```
convert -thumbnail 400x600 -background white -alpha remove " . escapeshellarg($pathToFile) . "[0]
```

The problem I have is the following :

```
ERROR loggerTechnique - [Script][OK][thumbnails][UP][document not converted ! (QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display)][thumbnails]
INFO loggerTechnique - [Script][OK][thumbnails][UP][Process n°24/63898 (RES_ID => 69276, FORMAT => pdf, PATH => /var/docservers/FASTHD_MAN/2017/10/0001//0929.pdf)][thumbnails]
```

Do you have an idea of why I have the `QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display` error ?

Comment: The `<something>: Could not connect to display` error is caused when a unix application is trying to connecto to a X Server display which is either unset or not existing. On a server you really typically don't have an X environment (GUI windowing system) installed. So, for some reason, imagemagick is trying to connect to your display.

Comment: Any fix for this problem ?

Comment: Sorry, someone better versed in convert will have to find out why. But my guess is that the pdf library used by imagemagick is dependant on Xcb, which in turn needs an active `$DISPLAY`. Not sure how to resolve the issue if that's the cause, though...

Comment: For a start you do not have an input file or if you have it should come after convert. Why not try something simple with a hardcoded file first and get that working?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Try using this form `convert input.pdf ... OPTIONS ... output.jpg`